# Removing SQL sever protocols from local machine

Tags: sql-server

How can I remove these instances totally and install a fresh SQL. I have uninstalled everything linking to SQL in my machine, but these protocols are still here in my computer management(local). I used revo uninstaller to uninstall

[image]

Comment: Why didn't you use the installer for SQL Server to uninstall them?

Comment: I don't know about it

Comment: So who installed the SQL Server instances if not you. I'd speak to them, though you might have borked the installs now, and so you may have a much harder time (properly) removing what ever remnants are left.

Comment: I installed them and used revo uninstaller to uninstall them, but it seems it never removed the protocols when performing the operation

Comment: *"I don't know about it"* Then  you do know about the installer... You could try using the installer the remove them, but like I said, they may well be quite borked now.

Comment: revo uninstaller removes and delete remnant files that was why I used it uninstall. How can I remove them

Comment: I also had SQL Server on my machine. I removed it using the built-in uninstall option in "Add/Remove programs" or "Apps and Features" (or whatever it is called in current versions of Windows, I lost track), and I don't have those "SQL Server Configuration Manager" entries lingering around. Thus, while I cannot help you solve your current problem, I can advise you, the next time you want to uninstall something, just use the built-in uninstaller provided by the software instead of some third-party uninstaller application.

Comment: Reinstall SQL server/tools and uninstall them NOT using some third party software.

Comment: The lesson to learn is: Many of those third-party "Windows optimization" software packages do more harm than good. Just use the built-in facilities, unless you have a *very* good reason to do otherwise.

Comment: Thanks guys.. I will install them and uninstall them again without using revo uninstaller